InValidOperationException: ChatMessage.UserName has property 'object' instead of 'String'

InvalidOperationException: The 'object' property
'ChatMessage.UserName' could not be mapped to the database type
'nvarchar(max)' because the database provider does not support mapping
'object' properties to 'nvarchar(max)' columns

The Above is the error message that I am getting as it shows on the page after trying to register
I tried to look up the problem but couldn't find a solution since the server is looking for a nvarchar instead of a Object to store as the Users Name.
I trust that the way I am accepting the input is correct, but if this is not then this could be the problem. The below is how I get the input from the user.
<div class="form-floating mb-3">
    <input asp-for="Input.UserName" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" />
    <label asp-for="Input.UserName">User Name</label>
</div>

This is the one field that I say that it should be String which is in my Register script
public string? UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new User
    {
        UserName = Input.UserName,
        Email = Input.Email,
        PasswordHash = HashPassword(Input.Password)
    };

    _context.Users.Add(user);

I know this is not much but if I can maybe just get a clue to what could be the problem it would help a great deal
I also have this part which is supposed to help store the users information for when they Login the next Time
public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide the actual error message. There are typos in it, which mean I don't trust what you have shared is the real error message.

This site requires that you provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue when asking us to help debug code. The complete, exact error message you're getting should also be in your post, so we have that information available. Please [edit] your post to provide those things, so that we can try to help.

I figured it out, I decided to go search for the UserName in the code search and found the culpret to be a UserName which was located not close to the problem, it was located in a script that was meant for another feauture
